# OmniGraffle: How to make line terminators connect to Center of objects, not to the edges of the objects?

Tags: omnigraffle

The following image illustrates the problem I am trying to solve with formatting when connecting lines to objects to OmniGraffle.

[image: How connected "Filled Center ball" terminators appear]

When I use lines, with "Filled Center Ball" terminators to connect the two empty circles, the lines run from center to center, yet the the terminators always  at the edge of the circle, as seen in the middle drawing, and never over the center of the connected objects.

I am wanting the terminator to terminate at the center of the circles, rather than the edges,  as shown in the 3rd drawing.

Obviously, I can produce these (since you see a pair in the third drawing) by setting the end connectors to none, and then creating additional, slightly smaller black circles and pasting them on the center of the other circles.

I imagine that there is some way to force the ball connector lines to be centered over the center point of the circles, not the edge, but I can't find any description of how to do that.

Can you help?